# Django Rest Framework: Creating a serializer with a ListField causes circular dependency error

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and Rest Framework.  I'm following the documentation on serializers and am trying to create a ListField (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield)
and when I do I get a nasty circular import error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'api.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

My serializers file appears as:

```
class CapacitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    planeIds = serializers.ListField(
        planeId = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=10)
    )
    passangerNums = serializers.ListField(
        passangerNum = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    )
    litersPerMinute = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    minutesOfFlight = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
```

The code would work if I simply left the code as:

```
    class CapacitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        planeId = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=10)
        passangerNum = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
        litersPerMinute = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
        minutesOfFlight = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
```

Any idea why this error is being thrown?
Additionally If I expect my data to be lists of planeIds and passengerNums is this not a good way to go about it?

versions:
Django==3.0.4
djangorestframework==3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

The documentation linked required the use of the child parameter.  Child is required and not a placeholder name